# How to enumerate theorems with A.1, A.2 and so on

Tags: numbering, theorems

I'm currently using

```
\newtheorem{lemma}[abc]{Lemma A.}
```

but the spacing is off. abc is just a counter here. Can I instead have the A. be part of the enumeration? Or is there a way to remove the space after "Lemma A."?
The enumeration should just be A.1, A.2, A.3 and so on, the letter A never changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine the `abc` counter representation to *always* be preceded by `A.`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{abc}
\newtheorem{lemma}[abc]{Lemma}
\renewcommand{\theabc}{A.\arabic{abc}}

\begin{document}

Also see Lemma~\ref{lem:third}.
\begin{lemma}
  First lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[second]
  Second lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[last]
  Third lemma.\label{lem:third}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```